# Android NDK with Studio on Mac: Unrecognized opcode

Tags: android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

New to Android NDK development, I am trying to get an Android app designed to build under Eclipse for Linux using ndkBuild to build under Android Studio on the Mac.

It is failing assembly with "unrecognized opcode".  I assume this is some kind  cross-compilation issue for the target processor, but I have no idea how this is configured with ndkBuild.  The Linux header files needed to do this compilation were copied from an Ubuntu VM on the same Mac.

Any idea how to resolve this assembly error?

Here's my build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "net.kismetwireless.android.pcapcapture"
    minSdkVersion 13
    targetSdkVersion 15

    ndk {
        moduleName "libpcap"
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            cFlags "-Wno-return-type"
        }
    }

}

externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path "src/main/jni/Android.mk"
    }
}
```

And my Android.mk looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libpcap
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
    libpcap-1.3.0/pcap-linux.c \
    libpcap-1.3.0/fad-null.c \
    libpcap-1.3.0/pcap.c \
    libpcap-1.3.0/inet.c \
    libpcap-1.3.0/gencode.c \
    libpcap-1.3.0/optimize.c \
    libpcap-1.3.0/nametoaddr.c \
    libpcap-1.3.0/etherent.c \
    libpcap-1.3.0/savefile.c \
    libpcap-1.3.0/sf-pcap.c \
    libpcap-1.3.0/sf-pcap-ng.c \
    libpcap-1.3.0/pcap-common.c \
    libpcap-1.3.0/bpf_image.c \
    libpcap-1.3.0/bpf_dump.c \
    libpcap-1.3.0/scanner.c \
    libpcap-1.3.0/grammar.c \
    libpcap-1.3.0/bpf_filter.c \
    libpcap-1.3.0/version.c \
    pcap_jni.c
#include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -DSYS_ANDROID=1 -Dyylval=pcap_lval -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -D_U_="__attribute__((unused))" -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/libpcap-1.3.0
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

My error output looks like this when running `./gradlew build`:

```
  /var/folders/k6/80v30vf13kdc8qd2rjtq35640000gn/T/pcap-linux-60f203.s: Assembler messages:
  /var/folders/k6/80v30vf13kdc8qd2rjtq35640000gn/T/pcap-linux-60f203.s:357: Error: unrecognized opcode `rorw $8,$23'
...
  /var/folders/k6/80v30vf13kdc8qd2rjtq35640000gn/T/pcap-linux-60f203.s:8369: Error: unrecognized opcode `rorw $8,$2'
  clang: error: assembler command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  make: *** [/Users/dyoung/workspace/wireless-r/android-pcap-studio/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/mips64/objs/pcap/libpcap-1.3.0/pcap-linux.o] Error 1
```

Comment: You should not copy headers from Ubuntu. Try to find the corresponding headers in Android repo on googlesource.com. Anyways, your failure is for MIPS architecture. Are you sure you will ever run your library on such device? I recommend to begin with running `ndk-build V=1` from command line, and analyzing the log.

Comment: You are right, I cannot copy the headers from Ubuntu for x86.  As a newbie here, I did not realize the headers were architecture specific.  Clearly they are.  And, yes, I don't need MIPS, so I added `abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"` to my build.gradle.  But now I need headers for that architecture.  Android NDK includes some headers, but it does not include the needed Linux Kernel headers like `linux/net_tstamp.h`, so I must get these from somewhere.

Comment: FWIW, `linux/net_tstamp.h` can be found in NDK (for platforms 21 and higher). But you can always take the kernel headers from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/kernel-headers

Comment: Darn, you are right, it is there!  For some reason my build isn't picking up that include folder automatically, so I incorrectly assumed it wasn't there... but that is a different problem!  Thanks, @alex-cohn.   You should format this as an answer so I can accept it.  The key things I learned from you that solved my problem are that (1) I should not copy headers from another install as they are architecture-specific, and (2) that I can get them for ARM from the NDK installation in $ANDRIOD-SDK-HOME/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android build, use Android header files. If some header is not available in NDK, you can use  [android.googlesource.com/platform/external/kernel-headers](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/kernel-headers).

Note that these headers depend on the ABI and [API level](https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html). If some header is missing or incomplete in NDK for android-14 but can be found for android-21 it does not necessarily mean that the required kernel function is not available, but you should be extra careful.

The latest NDK r14 proposed a new way to use the Android header files, which they call [Unified headers](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk.git/+/master/docs/UnifiedHeaders.md). This switch should reduce the hassle and make Android builds easier. But this feature has not been tested enough yet.

Comment: Thanks, @alex-cohn.  Super helpful!